# socketio-jwt disconnect expired tokens

Tags: node.js, socket.io, jwt

I am able to authenticate using socketio-jwt and everything is working great. The problem I'm running into is if I set an expiration to a minimum time and let it expire I can continue to emit and receive messages on the connection. As long as I don't refresh the page the connection persists. Once I refresh the connection is disconnected and I am required to reconnect. Is it possible to have the server check for expired tokens and disconnect the connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The library does not support this feature, you can validate the token on each socket io event that you want.

In a [Github Issue](https://github.com/auth0-community/socketio-jwt/issues/38#issuecomment-85336978) a contributor answered with this analogy:

The id_token is like your national
passport, both have an expiration, you can enter a country as long as your
passport is not expired and most countries will not keep track of
expiration to hunt you down.

You can handle this manually using a socketio middleware for example:

```
const timer = require('long-timeout')

function middleware (socket, next) {
  const decodedToken = socket.user // Assuming the decoded user is save on socket.user

  if (!decodedToken.exp) {
    return next()
  }

  const expiresIn = (decodedToken.exp - Date.now() / 1000) * 1000
  const timeout = timer.setTimeout(() => socket.disconnect(true), expiresIn)

  socket.on('disconnect', () => timer.clearTimeout(timeout))

  return next()
}
```

Comment: @Woodsy can you mark my answer as correct, in case you think is the correct one of course.